# Cannot change the desktop wallpaper in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, sudo

I tried installing **GNOME** packages to Ubuntu 14.04(unity).
I used these codes.

> sudo apt-get install gdm
>
> sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
>
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install gnome-weather gnome-music gnome-maps cheese gnome-documents

That did not do well, So i removed them completely using

> sudo apt-get remove gdm
>
> sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
>
> sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop

And now i am not able to change my desktop wallpaper.**A right click on desktop is not working**. I think it removed the necessary packages of Unity also .Even the login screen display has not changed from GNOME style to Unity style.
Is there a way to regain the original Ubuntu unity style?

Comment: I have the exact same issue after installing then uninstalling gnome. Did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it works for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

However this case fits more to AskUbuntu, and almost indentical one has been answered:
[Desktop shows a white or black background instead of wallpapers](https://askubuntu.com/q/287571/39017) (the solution above comes from there).

I had tried to comment your question but I have been unable to do it by lack of 50 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall Unity (default for Ubuntu) you can type in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After a reboot you should be able to choose a wallpaper again.

Comment: It did not work. I still face the same problem